# Mysql query: count column

Tags: mysql

Hi all guys i have a technical problem, i have a table with records like this:

```
DATE        SIP DURATION  TYPE
2017-02-22  670    9      NO ANSWER
2017-02-22  670    9      ANSWER
2017-02-22  670    9      ANSWER
2017-02-22  671    9      NO ANSWER
```

i'd like have result like this:

```
SIP   DURATION  NOANSWER  ANSWER
670     18         1        2
671     9          1        0
```

i'll make query like this:

```
select 
DISTINCT(SIP),
(select count(*) FROM table where TYPE="ANSWERED")
(select count(*) FROM table where TYPE="NO ANSWERED")
from table
```

but the result count all record on the table, is better use group by?

sorry i'm noob :(
thanks for the time
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is easier to use `GROUP BY` with conditional `SUM` and `COUNT` like the following example:

```
SELECT 
    SIP,
    SUM(CASE TYPE WHEN 'ANSWER' THEN DURATION ELSE 0 END) AS DURATION,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'NO ANSWER' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NOANSWER,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'ANSWER' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ANSWER
FROM table_name
GROUP BY SIP
```

> **Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1142/2/0